# ASP.NET Core Identity, load user's claims when pulling a user from the database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

If your database context inherits from `IdentityDbContext<User>`, then your context gets properties like `UserClaims` and `RoleClaims`. These can be used to get (say) a user's claims as follows...

```cs
User jim = await Context.Users.SingleAsync(u => u.Name == "Jim");
List<IdentityUserClaim<string>> claims = await Context
  .UserClaims
  .Where(c => c.UserId == jim.Id)
  .ToListAsync();
```

However, this seems somewhat clunky. I would have expected to be able to do the following...

```cs
User jim = await Context.Users
  .Include(u => u.UserClaims)
  .SingleAsync(u => u.Name == "Jim");
```

However this doesn't compile. If you change it to include `u.Claims` then it compiles, but throws an exception... "*InvalidOperationException: The expression 'u.Claims' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'*"

Now I understand this, in that the `User` entity doesn't have a `Claims` navigation property (although I'm not sure where Intellisense picks up the `Claims` property), but I'm surprised that this isn't something provided when you set up Identity.

Am I missing something here, or do I have to make two database calls to get the user and claims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you are right, it doesn't have navigation property by default.

You could try follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-navigation-properties) to add the navigation property yourself:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

Dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            // Each User can have many UserClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
```