# What's the proper way to create new roles in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-7.0

I'm working on a site in .NET 7, and I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how to actually create new roles. The best I can figure so far is that I need to manually insert the roles into the AspNetRoles table. While I'm more than willing to do that, I'd prefer a programmatic solution so I don't need to run scripts on every environment the site is deployed to.

I've reviewed some of the pages ([[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0) [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) on roles and authorization in NET 7, but all I can find is information about adding users to a role, or how to ensure users have a certain role to access content. I can't find anything that discusses how to actually create the roles themselves.

I've found a few posts on Stack Overflow which discus this, but they're all for much older versions of .NET (newest I found was from 2017). I know there's been some fairly major changes to .NET in the past few years, so I'm not keen on using what are likely outdated and obsolete procedures for managing roles.

I can only assume my google-fu is failing me here, and I just can't track down the official .NET 7 docs which discuss this.

**What's the proper way to create new roles in .NET 7?**

Comment: Have you considered add a migration inserting these roles you need in database?

Comment: @DouglasFerreira I'm running against a really old database (originally built for a .NET 2 site), so I've avoided running any migrations. Far from ideal, but it's the situation I've been handed. Thanks for the suggestion though, as using a migration didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

Add Role related services with`.AddRoles<TRole>()` method:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(..........)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDbContext>();
```

I tried as below in a scaffolded Register.cshtml.cs:

inject related services:

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
private readonly IRoleStore<IdentityRole> _roleStore;



public RegisterModel(...., RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IRoleStore<IdentityRole> roleStore)
{
  .....
_roleManager = roleManager;
_roleStore = roleStore;
}
```

Create a role and add the user to th role:

```
var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                var role = Activator.CreateInstance<IdentityRole>();
                await _roleStore.SetRoleNameAsync(role, "Admin", CancellationToken.None);
                
                //you'd better check if the role exists first,I omitted the codes here
                
                var roleresult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if (roleresult.Succeeded)
                {
                    var addtoroleresult=await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                }
```

After the codes excuted, :

[image]
[image]

Check if user is in role:

```
_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)
```

Also,IdentityUser doesn't have navigation property by default
If you want to access related roles,you may follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76576146/asp-net-core-identity-load-users-claims-when-pulling-a-user-from-the-database/76578883#76578883)

Comment: I'll give this a try later today. Will accept once I've got it working. Thank you!